# How to combine 2 columns in sql and sort

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to sort 2 tables which have channels and views as columns.  I need to combine both the channels and the views into 2 new columns and display them.

My code I have tried:

```
    SELECT IFNULL( youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed.channel,  '' ) + 
    IFNULL( most_popular_twitch_streamers.Channel,  '' ) AS channel, 
    IFNULL( youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed.views,  '' ) + 
    IFNULL( most_popular_twitch_streamers.Views,  '' ) AS views
    FROM youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed
    INNER JOIN most_popular_twitch_streamers
    ORDER BY  `views` DESC
```

I also tried CONCAT AND COASCE as well with no success.

Comment: What are the names of the columns in both tables?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` on what fields? could you provide more details please? `CREATE TABLE` for all tables as well as samples of source records and expected result can help a lot

Comment: I think (not certain) that you may want to UNION your two tables together - `SELECT channel, views FROM youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed UNION ALL SELECT Channel, Views FROM most_popular_twitch_streamers ORDER BY Views DESC`

Comment: @E_McAndrew Gareth D got the fields right, its channel and views from each table where none of the channels or views are the same

Comment: @GarethD that worked! thanks a lot, i had tried UNION but i must have been misusing it

Answer (score 0):

if queries is Ok but not sorted you can use your query as from statement

```
select channel,views from 
(
 SELECT IFNULL( youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed.channel,  '' ) + 
    IFNULL( most_popular_twitch_streamers.Channel,  '' ) AS channel, 
    IFNULL( youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed.views,  '' ) + 
    IFNULL( most_popular_twitch_streamers.Views,  '' ) AS views
    FROM youtube_gaming_channels_most_viewed
    INNER JOIN most_popular_twitch_streamer
    ) v order by views DESC
```